# jQuery Autocomplete multiple field

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have an issue with jQuery autocomplete on multiple field.
The standard behavior is to fill a field and an autocomplete appears. The user selects one and autocomplete add on different field the right value and user valid his form. **This is working like a charm.**

But I found some user that use copy/paste on autocomplete field and valid right next, so they submit a form with invalid data. Field can be blank so I can't test a mandatory field.

So my question is : how make an autocomplete, that fill all field on copy/paste ? (I have sample code if needed, but autocomplete is include inside a jqGrid and this is hard to read just for this problem).
Another way is how to know if all field is successfully filled (ajax response works well but it is not used by user that c/p).

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger the same behaviour on pasting by using something like

```
$('#autocomplete_field').bind('paste', trigger_action);
```